# Deleting existing data before loading new data using Spring data repository populator

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have configured Repository populator to load json data in mongodb at the time of application startup. Now if I rerun the application, populator will try to insert that data again which is causing duplication errors. I would like to first delete all existing data and then load it using populator.

I couldn't find any application.properties which can help me to do that.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I able to do this using following code,

```java
    @Bean   
    public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean getRespositoryPopulator(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {

        customerRepository.deleteAll();

        Resource customersTestData = new ClassPathResource("customers.json");

        Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(new Resource[]{customersTestData});

        return factory;
    }
```